# html helper for editable div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am trying to create an html helper for editable div. I am almost there as when I render the view I see the html markup on the viewsource but not on the view page. here something is wrong. Please help, what is wrong or what I am missing here...

C# Code

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    //namespace AnAReporting.HtmlHelpers
    namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
    {
        public static class EdiatableDivExtensions
        {
            public static string EdiatableDiv(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
            {
                return String.Format("<div for='{0}'>{1}</div>", target, text);
            }

            public static MvcHtmlString EdiatableDivFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string format, object htmlAttributes)
            {
                return htmlHelper.EdiatableDivFor(expression, format: format, htmlAttributes: HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
            }


            public static MvcHtmlString EdiatableDivFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
            {
                ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
                return EdiatableDivHelper(htmlHelper,
                                     metadata,
                                     metadata.Model,
                                     ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression),
                                     format,
                                     htmlAttributes);
            }

            private static MvcHtmlString EdiatableDivHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, object model, string expression, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
            {
                return InputHelper(htmlHelper,
                                   InputType.Text,
                                   metadata,
                                   expression,
                                   model,
                                   useViewData: false,
                                   isChecked: false,
                                   setId: true,
                                   isExplicitValue: true,
                                   format: format,
                                   htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes);
            }

            // Helper methods

            private static MvcHtmlString InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, string name, object value, bool useViewData, bool isChecked, bool setId, bool isExplicitValue, string format, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
            {
                string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();
                }

                TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
                tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);

                string valueParameter = htmlHelper.FormatValue(value, format);
                bool usedModelState = false;

                //switch (inputType)
                //{
                //    case InputType.CheckBox:
                //        bool? modelStateWasChecked = htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(bool)) as bool?;
                //        if (modelStateWasChecked.HasValue)
                //        {
                //            isChecked = modelStateWasChecked.Value;
                //            usedModelState = true;
                //        }
                //        goto case InputType.Radio;
                //    case InputType.Radio:
                //        if (!usedModelState)
                //        {
                //            string modelStateValue = htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string)) as string;
                //            if (modelStateValue != null)
                //            {
                //                isChecked = String.Equals(modelStateValue, valueParameter, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                //                usedModelState = true;
                //            }
                //        }
                //        if (!usedModelState && useViewData)
                //        {
                //            isChecked = htmlHelper.EvalBoolean(fullName);
                //        }
                //        if (isChecked)
                //        {
                //            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
                //        }
                //        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", valueParameter, isExplicitValue);
                //        break;
                //    case InputType.Password:
                //        if (value != null)
                //        {
                //            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", valueParameter, isExplicitValue);
                //        }
                //        break;
                //    default:
                //        string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
                //        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
                //        break;
                //}

                //usedModelState = true;
                tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", valueParameter, isExplicitValue);

                if (setId)
                {
                    tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
                }

                // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
                ModelState modelState;
                if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState))
                {
                    if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
                    }
                }

                tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));

                //if (inputType == InputType.CheckBox)
                //{
                //    // Render an additional <input type="hidden".../> for checkboxes. This
                //    // addresses scenarios where unchecked checkboxes are not sent in the request.
                //    // Sending a hidden input makes it possible to know that the checkbox was present
                //    // on the page when the request was submitted.
                //    StringBuilder inputItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                //    inputItemBuilder.Append(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

                //    TagBuilder hiddenInput = new TagBuilder("input");
                //    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
                //    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("name", fullName);
                //    hiddenInput.MergeAttribute("value", "false");
                //    inputItemBuilder.Append(hiddenInput.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
                //    return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputItemBuilder.ToString());
                //}

                //return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

                StringBuilder inputItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                inputItemBuilder.Append(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

                //TagBuilder divInput = new TagBuilder("div");
                //divInput.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.Hidden));
                //divInput.MergeAttribute("name", fullName);
                //divInput.MergeAttribute("value", "false");
                //inputItemBuilder.Append(divInput.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputItemBuilder.ToString());
            }

            private static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValueDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
            {
                return dictionary == null ? new RouteValueDictionary() : new RouteValueDictionary(dictionary);
            }



        }
    }
```

Calling html helper from the view...

```
          @Html.EdiatableDivFor(model => model.Remarks, null, new { style =                                      "display: block;"})
```

Page view source...

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-val="true" data-val-length="Minumum 25 and maximum 200 characters are Allowed" data-val-length-max="200" data-val-length-min="25" data-val-required="Please provide Remarks" id="Remarks" name="Remarks" style="display: block;" value="[TECH. REMARKS]: REPORT CASE45RT65CASE45RT65**[VERIFIER REMARKS]: REPORT REJECTED BY THE VERIFIER***[TECH. REMARKS]: REPORT MODIFIED BY TECHNICIAN**[JOB VERIFIED]" />
```

Comment: Your not setting the `InnerText` property of the div  - `tagBuilder.InnerText = valueParameter;`. But what is the point of this - your adding the `data-val-*` attributes used by unobtrusive client side validation but they will be completely ignored (they only work on form controls). And only form control values post back so any data you generate/edit will not be submitted.

Comment: Thanks dear. I set tagBuilder.SetInnerText(valueParameter); and it worked.

Comment: Dear Stephen, I have a requirement where a user enter remarks. I was using the text area for this. But now we have a new requirement where when a user enter new remark it should be appended to the existing remarks and every time when a new remark is added it should be displayed in a different color. And we can do this color thing with the text area. Do you have any suggestion for this so that the editable div data can be posted back and validation will also work. Please help.

Comment: **And we can not do this color thing with the text area.

Comment: And you cannot use validation attributes on a div, nor can you post back its contents (at least without javascript/jquery). Delete your extension method (its pointless). Without knowing more about exactly what you need to do its impossible to help. For example, do you use ajax to save each comment one at a time or do you want to post them all back at once?

Comment: Actually this is a workflow application. Here one user is technician who enter some form data including remarks field related to a job. Then after the report is submitted it goes to verifier (another user in the workflow). verifier opens this report and enters his remarks before approving or rejecting it. Here I am appending the remarks of the verifier along with the remarks of the technician in one single textarea on the UI and there is only one field for remarks in the database as well. Now the requirement is to display the remarks by diff.

Comment: user in diff. color. But this is not possible with text-area. So I was trying to do it using a div. I hope this clears the issue in hand. I would really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Based on your description I suggest you have a serious flaw in the design of your database and models. You should have either 2 'remarks' fields (for the technician and verifier) or a separate table for remarks if there could be more than just the 2 parties involved in adding remarks.

Comment: Yes I know that. But this requirement came later on. And the application is up and running and in production. So I am looking for a workaround for this situation in hand. Earlier maintaining remarks history was not a requirement and we were just over-writing the existing remarks. Please suggest if can help somehow keeping in mind the current constraint. I can not change the database now.